# Will python prompt for input from user as a Visual Studio Console application does? if yes please give an example

Tags: python, visual-studio, console-application

Will python prompt for input from user as a Visual Studio Console application does? if yes please give an  example.

Comment: Give an example of what you mean first. Not all of us know what a Visual Studio Console application does that you are asking about.

Answer (score 1):

Do you need something like this? This works with **Python 3.6+**

```
name = input('Your name: ')
print(f'Hello {name}')
```

Comment: I tried your statements, yes, it is what I was looking for. Thanks.